# Add Navigation Drawer with Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android

In my app there is Bottom Navigation Bar i want to add Navigation Drawer because there is many buttons that dont fit at Bottom Navigation Bar.
i tried many ways but unfortunately none of them worked 
here is my Bottom Navigation Bar xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent2"
    tools:context=".UI.HomeActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">



    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fcff38"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"
        app:itemTextColor="#303132"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame1"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any answer could help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'NavigationView' class in the layout, also wrap the root view group inside DrawerLayout.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    ...
    </FrameLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This post will help you: [NavigationView](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/)